# jquery gallery doesn't fully work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a gallery in my website (on my computer, not on a server yet) and I have a problem on it. here is it's script(it's loaded from the server by php):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery').hide();
    $('.gallery:first').fadeIn();
    var galleryItems=$('.gallery').length;
    var index=0;
    setInterval(function() 
    {
        index++ ;
        var id="gallery-"+(index);
        $('.gallery').hide();
        if (index==galleryItems)
        {
            index=0;
        }
        $('#gallery-'+index).fadeIn(1000);
    },7000);
});
```

The gallery works, but after some time that I'm not looking on the gallery it stop working correctly.

This is how it supposed to look:

[picture 1](http://ufu.co.il/viewer.php?file=311wvzb26dvi9tfrvoui.bmp)

This is how it actually looks:

[picture 2](http://ufu.co.il/viewer.php?file=kky6caraiacl1bjaiwzi.bmp)

What should I do?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a live demo that we can see in action, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or similar..? That we can see it working, and can edit it to find the problems and offer solutions.

Comment: Oops.. I think I messed up your [rating system](http://ufu.co.il/viewer.php?file=311wvzb26dvi9tfrvoui.bmp), sorry.

Comment: I don't think so, I used php and JS Fiddle and similar don't do that

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when the `index==galleryItems` you are fading in item 0 instead of the last item. Then when the gallery continues it fades in the next item, resulting in doubling.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery').hide();
    $('.gallery:first').fadeIn();
    var galleryItems=$('.gallery').length;
    var index=0;
    setInterval(function() 
    {
        index++ ;
        //var id="gallery-"+(index); this is unused so it should be removed.
        $('.gallery').hide();
        $('#gallery-'+index).fadeIn(1000); // MOVED TO BEFORE INDEX RESET
        if (index==galleryItems)
        {
            index=0;
        }

    },7000);
});
```

Comment: then you have proven that this is not the code causing the problem

Comment: so what is causing the problem? that is what I'm asking